# Is the current density not uniquely defined?

Tags: electric-current, classical-electrodynamics

Given I know how the charge distribution $\rho(\vec{x}, t)$, I can define a vector $\vec{j}$ that is supposed to show the flow of this charge distribution. 
To do that, $\vec{j}$ only has to suffice 
\begin{align}
\partial_i j^i + \partial_t \rho = 0 
\end{align}

Thing is, given another divergence-free vectorfield $\vec{c}$, I could add it to $\vec{j}$ without changing above equation. So I ask: Is there an ambiguity in the definition of $\vec{j}$?

Comment: Imagine if there was only one solution to that equation. Then there would be only one possible current density that could be found in the universe, and it wouldn't depend on the physical structure the current is flowing in, or the sources or fields nearby. The current density in an AWG 000 wire connected to mains would be the same as in an AWG 30 wire connected to a 9 V batter and the same as in a region of vacuum with no energy sources nearby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no ambiguity in the definition of $\vec j.$ It is not defined by that equation. It only satisfies it.

The definition of $\vec j$ is that $\int_D \vec{j} \cdot d\vec{S}$ should equal the net current passing any surface $D$.

Comment: You might want to share what the definition of $\vec{j}$ is.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp. I've now added a definition. It might not be the best definition, but I don't think that the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Current_density&oldid=852869176#Definition) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Charge density $\rho$ known for every point x in the whole space does not uniquely define current density $\mathbf j$. $\mathbf j$ is largely independent of $\rho$, one can have non-zero $\mathbf j$ of any value even if $\rho=0$ (current inside wires).

Comment: If there is a current, then there is charge, isn't there? So how can $\rho$ be equal to zero?

Comment: @Filippo. Consider a region filled with an equal amount of positive and negative charges so that they on average cancel in every part of the region. Then $\rho=0.$ Now let the positive charges move in the direction of the positive $x$ axis. Then $\mathbf j \neq 0$ but still $\rho=0.$

Comment: @md2perpe Why is $\bf j\neq 0$? Wouldn't $\bf j=0$ solve the continuity equation?

Comment: @Filippo. Positive charges in movement gives a current density. The negative charges are not moving and don't give a cancelling current density. Yes, $\mathbf j=\mathbf 0$ would *also* solve the continuity equation, but that's not the correct current density.

Comment: @md2perpe "Positive charges in movement gives a current density" - This makes sense, but I wonder what the underlying definition is...

Comment: @Filippo. I gave one possible definition in [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/431933/149169).