# Is the continuity equation used to **define** the current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, conservation-laws, density

Recall the continuity equation:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho+\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot J}=0$$
Given $\rho$, there is obviously not a unique solution $\boldsymbol{J}$, but I guess one could choose an additional requirement (e.g. some condition on the rotation) such that there is a unique solution (by the Helmholtz theroem?). The idea may be to pick the most "obvious" solution. So I hope that someone can elaborate on the mathematical aspect and tell us if this is actually done in practice.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431906/237923) is a strongly related question that I just found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the current from knowing only $\dot \rho$ you will need extra information such as the electrical conductivity. If
$$
{\bf J}= \sigma {\bf E}=- \sigma \nabla \phi
$$
then you have
$$
\dot \rho- \sigma \nabla^2 \phi=0,
$$
which can be solved with suitable boundary conditions.

Comment: @Fillipo, there's no mathematical reason. It's an observed fact called Ohm's Law. In many materials (or in vacuum) it doesn't apply.

Comment: For future readers: The question was why we can expect to find a solution of the continuity equation that is of the form $\sigma\bf E$.

Comment: We may be lucky and find a constant $\sigma$ such that the second equation holds, but if $\sigma$ is a non-constant solution, then $\sigma\bf E$ is not necessarely a solution of the continuity equation, is it? Instead, we have to find a solution of$$\dot \rho=\sigma \nabla^2 \phi+\nabla\sigma\cdot\nabla\phi,$$ don't we?

Comment: @Filippo: Yes. If $\sigma$ varies the equations involves $\partial_i \sigma(x) \partial \phi$ as you say.  It's still $\dot \rho+\nabla \cdot (\sigma {\bf E})=0$, though.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. So as @ThePhoton pointed out we are requiring that the continuity equation **and** Ohm's law hold.

Answer (score 2):

The continuity equation is not the definition of the current density.

One way to define the current density $\mathbf J(\mathbf r)$ is via the three components $J_x(\mathbf r), J_y(\mathbf r), J_z(\mathbf r)$ where

\begin{equation}
J_x(\mathbf r) = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{I_x(\mathbf r, s)}{\pi s^2}
\end{equation}

where the notation $I_x(\mathbf r, s)$ means the current passing in the positive x-direction through a disk that is perpendicular to the x-axis, centered around the point $\mathbf{r}$, with radius $s$. $J_y$ and $J_z$ are defined similarly. If you choose to use this definition, you might have to do a bit of work to show that the $\bf J$ so defined actually transforms as a vector. However, I think it has pedagogical value in the context of this question: it shows that "current density" is fundamentally nothing more than current per unit area.

Comment: @Filippo No, it isn't. As you pointed out in the question, the continuity equation doesn't give you a unique solution for $\bf J$. Directly defining $\bf J$ as current per unit area, as I showed, actually _defines_ $\bf J$.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/431933/237923) is similar and defines the current density through$$\forall A:I=\int_A\boldsymbol{J\cdot\text{d}A}$$which I guess is a stronger requirement than the continuity equation, i.e.$$\forall V:\dot Q=\int_{\partial V}\boldsymbol{J\cdot\text{d}A}.$$